# Vim's jumplist has always only one entry

Tags: vim, jump-list

I'm learning to use the jumps (CTRL-O, CTRL-I). But vim's jumplist allways has only one entry no matter how many jumps I make. Tried with `/`, `(` and `)`.
Anyone knows why ? I'm not loading any .vimrc.

**Edit:**

Explaining better how I'm testing this:
I created the following text:

```
djklfhsadkjfh ksjdf hskadf hskldjfhwelkrj hewlkjrg hewkr ghlwekrjhg klevhw. djklfhsadkjfh ksjdf hskadf hskldjfhwelkrj hewlkjrg hewkr ghlwekrjhg klevhw.  djklfhsadkjfh ksjdf hskadf hskldjfhwelkrj hewlkjrg hewkr ghlwekrjhg klevhw.  djklfhsadkjfh ksjdf hskadf hskldjfhwelkrj hewlkjrg hewkr ghlwekrjhg klevhw.  djklfhsadkjfh ksjdf hskadf hskldjfhwelkrj hewlkjrg hewkr ghlwekrjhg klevhw.  djklfhsadkjfh ksjdf hskadf hskldjfhwelkrj hewlkjrg hewkr ghlwekrjhg klevhw.  djklfhsadkjfh ksjdf hskadf hskldjfhwelkrj hewlkjrg hewkr ghlwekrjhg klevhw.  djklfhsadkjfh ksjdf hskadf hskldjfhwelkrj hewlkjrg hewkr ghlwekrjhg klevhw.  djklfhsadkjfh ksjdf hskadf hskldjfhwelkrj hewlkjrg hewkr ghlwekrjhg klevhw.  djklfhsadkjfh ksjdf hskadf hskldjfhwelkrj hewlkjrg hewkr ghlwekrjhg klevhw.  djklfhsadkjfh ksjdf hskadf hskldjfhwelkrj hewlkjrg hewkr ghlwekrjhg klevhw.
```

then I used `$` to go to line end, then I used `(` to go some phases before. In `:h jumps`, I read that ( is a jump. But when I see jump list (`:jumps`)  after the `(`, there is only 1 jump all the time.

Comment: If you don't have a vimrc you most likely are in compatible mode. (Which is very limited). Create a vimrc (put `set nocompatible` in it) and tell us if the results change. My guess is that it will.

Comment: Made that. Same thing. <C-O> and <C-I> simply don't work. I see only 1 jump in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that example text is one single line, only one jump is recorded. A jump has to go to a different line to appear in the jump list. You can also explicitly record a jump point via `m'`, but also only one in a line.

Comment: I returned to the documentation in order to see why this weren't obvious to me. And if you read :h jumps you'll see that this is only implicit to say the least. Also when you read http://bit.ly/12TK0oM, you aren't told this explicitly. You have to deduct it. So I edited the wiki, to make this more clear. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for improving the Wiki! Yes, it's only implicit in: _If you use a jump command, the current line number is inserted at the end of the jump list.  If the same line was already in the jump list, it is removed._